# Performing segue where Navigation Bar stays and Tab Bar disapears

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar, uitabbar, uistoryboardsegue

My app design consist of a `UITabBarController` and `UINavigationController`. I have some `UITableViews` that serve the purpose of enabling the user to select a file to play - and then it segues to a `AudioPlayer` class. I have several different ways of entering the `AudioPlayer` through the Tab bar and therefore I want to remove the Tab bar once the Player is active and only display a `UINavigationController` so the user can return back to were he previously was.

If I do a Push style segue, both the `UITabBar` and `UINavigationBar` stay. If I do a modal segue - both go away. How can I have the `UINavigationBar` stay, and the `UITabBar` disappear?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To hide the tab bar you can use hidesBottomBarWhenPushed. For instance:

```
  MyController *myController = [[MyController alloc]init]; 
  myController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
  [self.navigationController pushViewController:myController animated:YES];
  [myController release];
```

To hide the status bar you can use:

```
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
```

To hide the nav bar you can use:

```
  self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
```

I guess that is all you need and then some. Good luck. :)